# Why and when should trait and object have same name?

Tags: scala, traits, companion-object

What is the reason that

```
  trait Dog {
    def bark = "woof"
  }
  object Dog extends Dog
```

works, but the following does not

```
trait Dog {
  def bark = "woof"
}
class Dog extends Dog
```

I read somewhere that in the first case mentioned above the object is not a companion object. What is the scenario when object and trait should have the same name ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From introduction to Chapter 2 ([Identifiers, Names & Scopes](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html)):

> There are two different name spaces, one for **types** and one for **terms**.

Section 5.5 ([Object definitions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions)) contains almost exactly your example (with `Point` instead of `Dog`), with the following comment:

> Note that the double use of the name `Point` is legal, since the class definition defines the name Point in the **type** name space, whereas the object definition defines a name in the **term** namespace.

*(emphasis mine)*

Your second example with `class Dog extends Dog` does not work, because both the `class Dog` and `trait Dog` end up in the namespace for types, and this results in a conflict.

Companion `object`s are used whenever you would use static methods in e.g. Java (except that companion objects are much nicer, because they are, well, *objects*, and can be passed around as ordinary values).

The situation `object Foo extends Foo` appears somewhat contrived and rather uncommon. Have you an actual example where it is used? If not, then it's just a corner case that is formally valid, simply because it's not explicitly prohibited.

**EDIT**: [`object AnsiColor extends AnsiColor`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/AnsiColor$.html) seems to be one of the most "important" applications of the `object X extends X` pattern.

Comment: It is used in the standard library, take a look to the [`scala.util.Random` **object**](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.8/src/library/scala/util/Random.scala#L149) - it appears that this use case is to provide default instances of their companion **classes** / **traits** - however the lack of documentation about it, makes me think that, maybe it is not intended to be commonly used.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the second example fails here, is *not* because Dog is not a companion object, but because you define a new duplicate class Dog. I always view `traits` and `classes` as one category, and `objects` as another - and `object` is an singleton instance of either trait or class.

Why you can't create classes with the same name? 
It's impossible to distinguish two entities if that's allowed.

Why you *can* create (class/trait) and object with the same name?
You can distinguish them, because `class` or `trait` is *type* and object is a *value*.

When should you name your objects the same name as classes?
If you wan't to define companion object, so your implicits for the object would work. Or if you want to define convenient `apply` method on an object. Otherwise I don't bother myself at all with either object is `companion` or not, but often create objects with the class name for convenience.